# How can I determine which taskbar application/windows are requesting user attention

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar

I'd like to know how to get a list of the windows requiring user attention from the Windows taskbar. Windows requiring attention appear with a flashing orange color within the Windows taskbar.

Un-focused MSN Messenger conversation windows are a good example of this behavior: they turn orange as soon as a remote user sends an instance message.

My code targets the Windows 7 platform, but working on older Windows OS would be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe HSHELL_FLASH you get notified about by calling [RegisterShellHookWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644989(VS.85).aspx) is what you are after.