# How do I hook another applications events?

Tags: winapi, events, hook, notifications

I'd like to hook the event that is triggered when an application is trying to notify you of something (when its icon background turns orange and starts flashing) so  that I can create my own custom notifications (like getting a text message or email)

For example I'd like to have an event triggered when I receive an instant message on my computer that will send a message to my phone so I can respond appropriately.

How would I go about doing this?

Preferably I'd like something that could hook any notification event (then do the filtering inside the application, and something that works on windows XP and up)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine which taskbar application/windows are requesting user attention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791895/how-can-i-determine-which-taskbar-application-windows-are-requesting-user-attenti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [How can I determine which taskbar application/windows are requesting user attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791895/how-can-i-determine-which-taskbar-application-windows-are-requesting-user-attenti) ? Anyway, use [RegisterShellHookWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644989%28VS.85%29.aspx) and catch HSHELL_FLASH